# ASP.Net Core - How do I wait for User Identity to be available immediately after signing in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, httpcontext

I have a fairly standard Login action, but I want to change the redirect depending on the user role.
However, there's some sort of race condition going on: `HttpContext.User` says it yielded no results, causing the admin user to be redirected to the wrong homepage.

How do I 'wait' correctly until the HttpContext.User is available after signing in?

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginDto loginDto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(loginDto);
    }

    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginDto.Username, loginDto.Password, true, false);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(loginDto);
    }

    // This check doesn't always work because User = null
    if(HttpContext.User.IsInRole(RoleEnum.Administrator.ToString())){
        return LocalRedirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "Admin" }));
    }
    return LocalRedirect(loginDto.ReturnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
}
```

Comment: `User` is available only after authenticating not after signing-in. The signing-in will set some cookie to the response but it's in the scope of the mvc middleware, (already passed the authentication middleware). Of course you can set it manually by somehow. I'm just trying to provide a bit of info about why it's not working. There may be several solutions including one that is based on the Identity directly without involving the middlewares pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User UserManager instead of HttpContext in this scope like below

```
var userInRole = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role);
```